# Generate Tessellations looping through all shapefiles from folder in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder?

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, hexagonal-grid, tesselation

I am trying to create Hexagonal grids for each shapefile in a folder. I opted for ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder tool and was successful in creating a loop that reads and loads shapefile in the memory. But afterwards, I am trying to grab the extents of each shapefile and want to generate Hexagonal grids for each polygon. Struggled a lot and still have not figured out where the issue is.

Attached copy of model that I built for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arcpy as an alternative to ModelBuilder:

```py
import arcpy, os

input_workspace = r'C:\Test\Inputshapes' #Change, can also be a file geodatabase, if so add .gdb
output_workspace = r'C:\Test\Out_Tessellation' #Change, can also be a file geodatabase, if so add .gdb

arcpy.env.workspace = input_workspace
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() #List all feature classes in input_workspace

for fc in fclist:
    arcpy.GenerateTessellation_management(Output_Feature_Class=os.path.join(output_workspace,'Tessellation_'+fc), 
                                         Extent=arcpy.Describe(fc).Extent, 
                                         Shape_Type='HEXAGON', 
                                         Size='1 SquareKilometers', 
                                         Spatial_Reference=arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BERA. The code helps to overcome the road block that I had in model builder.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the help file [syntax section for Generate Tessellation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/generatetesellation.htm#GUID-E2723EF7-2BEF-4ACF-B78E-EACEC89DFFD2) its second parameter is Extent and its data type is Extent.

The output of your iterator is a FEATURECLASS, hopefully you'll agree this is not an EXTENT.

@BERA code extracts this property from the input featureclass so that the correct parameter type is fed into the tool.

The salient part is this:

```
arcpy.Describe(fc).Extent
```

If you want to keep your model you need to be looking at the model only [Calculate Value](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm#) tool to extract the extent from your FeatureClass and feed that into the parameter of the tessellation tool.

So @BERA has shown you the code you need to use, I've told you which tool you can do this in you just need to put it all together.

Comment: Nice, this is the correct answer. Tessellation was accepting the output from iterate feature classes as extent, but with an confusing error when executing

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks for the help. Its make sense and agree with you as GenerateTessellation expects Extent details.