# Using Calculate Value to get extent of feature to input into Generate Tessellation tool

Tags: modelbuilder, extents, python-parser, calculate-values, tesselation

Here is what my model looks like:

- Takes Excel with lat/long and plots points
- Splits by name field
- Iterate
- And buffer into separate `.gdb`
- Calculate value then pulls from the `buffer.gdb`

This is where I get lost:

- Inputs extent into Generate Tessellation

[image: Market Hex Builder]

I found this code from a separate question on here, but I haven't figured out how to input into the Calculate Value and then add the resulting extent into the tessellation.

```
arcpy.Describe(fc).Extent
```

Here is the other post; [Generate Tessellations looping through all shapefiles from folder in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308491/generate-tessellations-looping-through-all-shapefiles-from-folder-in-arcgis-pro)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the post by JeffreyBurka at the bottom of the thread here:
https://community.esri.com/t5/modelbuilder-questions/calculate-and-use-extent-of-feature-class-in-model/m-p/1087260#M3476

> Basically, the function needs to return a string, not an extent
> object; the output type is being set to enable you to chain items in
> ModelBuilder but isn't actually relevant to the value you return! What
> worked for me was to return a string in the format "xmin ymin xmax
> ymax" and set the output type to Extent. Arcpy/ModelBuilder are smart
> enough to know from the output type that you should be able to use the
> output of your function as input to an Extent parameter of another
> tool, and are also smart enough to handle the coercion from the string
> formatting of the extent to the expected Extent object.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, link-only answers are often removed or converted to comments, since links fail over time. While you can certainly *reference* an answer in another platform, your Answer really ought to address the highlights of the linked post, making following it optional.